# Dojo large UI organization

Tags: user-interface, dojo, code-organization

I'm working on a Dojotoolkit based JS application with lots of dialogs and formularies.
We are doing UI in a declarative way so or index.html file is really big.

Is there a way to organize the HTML code in a better way?
I know we can use href in our panels to load the content asynchronously by it difficults de debuging process.

Any tips or advices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not accepted any of the answers to your questions so far. Are you sure none of them qere helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider grouping up your things into fewer basic widget classes, so you only need to instantiale less stuff up front by yourself.